# How to ask for increase the budget for a freelancing project

Tags: freelance-websites, business-plan, budget, changes

I have agreed to work complete the mobile App project. The client had spoken to me expressing the idea of the App.

to give some Technical structure for their idea had designed supporting Database structure etc. then we have agreed on some amount.

But, Client has now come up with a new set of designs and screens which are high end required more working hours.

Now, I am wondering how to express my concern to the client and convince them to increase the budget for the App.

I am little afraid, how I should put my thoughts.

Can I ask for the partnership and pay me in profits, if so, please guide me pros & cons. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I would not advise the partnership/profits solution, and certainly not as a workaround. Because if there are profits, this will be in the long term, or never. Not counting that they will refuse.

Answer (score 2):

> ***"This isn't what was agreed upon. 
> I'll need to re-scope the project and provide a new cost estimate.***"

Be forthright, upfront, and honest about it. The client is certainly aware they've made additional changes.

As for getting compensation via an equity stake, that's an entirely different negotiation.